# Regex (PHP) match everything that starts at the beginning of the string or has a space+digit+/+space before it

Tags: php, regex

I have a string that looks like this:

```
1/ This is a string and it                                                                                   
has some text on a new line
2/ And then there's another string that has text only on one line
532/ Another string that has some year on a new line 
2020/xyz followed by some letters
720/ This is a match on the same line with another match but the other match won't be captured 721/ And this is the last line
```

I want to capture each string that starts with a number(`\d`) that's less than or equal to 3 dgits long(`{1,3}`) and has a forward slash (`/`) and is at the start of the string or has a space or new line before and after it (`\s+`).

This is how i want it to look like:

```
[Match 1] 1/ This is a string and it has some text on a new line
[Match 2] 2/ And then there's another string that has text only on one line
[Match 3] 532/ Another string that has some year on a new line 2020/xyz followed by some letters
[Match 4] 720/ This is a match on the same line with another match but the other match won't be captured
[Match 5] 721/ And this is the last line
```

This is my code so far:

```
$re = '/(\s|^)(?s)\d{1,3}+\/+\s+.*?(?=\d+\/+\s+|$)/m';
$str = '1/ This is a string and it 
has some text on a new line
2/ And then there\'s another string that has text only on one line
532/ Another string that has some year on a new line
2020/xyz followed by some letters
721/ And this is the last line ';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/w1bG70/1)

But the here are the problems:

1. It will not capture the string if two matches are on the same line (Match 4 and 5 will only capture Match 4)
2. It doesn't capture the string that's on a new line
3. It will not capture parts of a string that have numbers followed by / in them like `2020/xyz followed by some letters`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the anchor `$` that matches the end of the line (with the m modifier) to the `\z` anchor (that matches the end of the string whatever the modifiers).

This way the reluctant quantifier `.*?` will be able to match on several lines instead of stopping at the first end of line.

To find several occurrences on the same line, add `\s+` in the lookahead before the numbers. Otherwise the space before the numbers can't be consumed twice (once by `.*?` and once by `(\s|^)`).

```
~(\s|^)\d{1,3}/+\s.*?(?=\s+\d{1,3}/+\s|\z)~ms
```

Note that you can obtain a trimmed result using:

```
~(?<!\S)\d{1,3}/+\s.*?(?=\s+\d{1,3}/+\s|\s*\z)~s
```

To reduce the number of steps, you can change `\s.*?` to `(?>\s+\S+)*?` and remove the s modifier that is no more needed.

Comment: Hey, this is much much better but it still won't capture `2020/xyz followed by some letters` as part of `[Match 3]` :( For some reason it will cut at `[Match 3] 532/ Another string that has some year on a new line`

Comment: @Melody: [it does](https://regex101.com/r/ccMsAX/1)

Comment: Oh, it does. But another problem, if there are 4 digits and a space after `year/ ` it won't i should've specify this in my question: `362/ xyz xt wefef ascsfv alsld d5
2019/ fdsf adsd fdsf, e323rfef` should look like `[Match 6] 362/ xyz xt wefef ascsfv alsld d5
2019/ fdsf adsd fdsf, e323rfef` can you help me with this? X_X

Comment: Change `\d+` to `\d{1,3}`

Comment: This is amazing! <3 yey it works! But now the trimmed one won't work X_X. I'm using `trim(str_replace("\n", ' ', $match[$i]));` to trim it. Can it be done trough RegEx?

Comment: Can you please explain this atomic group `(?>\s+\S+)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
(?:\s|^)\d{1,3}\/\s(?:(?!\s\d{1,3}\/\s)[\s\S])*
```

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EdrgFl/1/)

```
<?php
$str = "1/ This is a string and it
has some text on a new line
2/ And then there's another string that has text only on one line
532/ Another string that has some year on a new line
2020/xyz followed by some letters
720/ This is a match on the same line with another match but the other match won't be captured 721/ And this is the last line";

preg_match_all('/(?:\s|^)\d{1,3}\/\s(?:(?!\s\d{1,3}\/\s)[\s\S])*/', $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($matches);
```

Prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1/ This is a string and it
has some text on a new line
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] =>
2/ And then there's another string that has text only on one line
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] =>
532/ Another string that has some year on a new line
2020/xyz followed by some letters
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] =>
720/ This is a match on the same line with another match but the other match won't be captured
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  721/ And this is the last line
        )

)
```